# Update a different model attributes after saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two different models: patients and samples. A patient can have several samples, and one sample belongs to a patient.

Here's the two models simplified (with only the info that I need for this problem...):

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :dateOfSample, :patient_attributes, :infantBreastFeedingAtThisTime, :typeBreastFeedingAtThisTime, :idadeDesmameAtThisTime

 belongs_to :patient
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient
end
```

And patient model:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :date_of_birth, :infant_name, :infantBreastFeeding, :typeBreastFeeding,:idadeDesmame
  has_many :samples
end
```

What I want to do is, every time a Sample is created or updated, if "dateOfSample" is the last sample available, I want to update patient attributes (:infantBreastFeeding, :typeBreastFeeding,:idadeDesmame) with the last particular sample attributes (:infantBreastFeedingAtThisTime, :typeBreastFeedingAtThisTime, :idadeDesmameAtThisTime)

How can I do this in the sample model? Using after_save? I tried but couldn't pass the patient attributes so it didn't recognize the patient... It should be a simple mistake I'm making, still rails noob :)

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I have a form to insert/update samples. Inside that form I have a partial for the patient fields (name and date birth). Sorry for not posting the form but it's too big...

Comment: Will samples always be added as nested attributes of the patient form?

Comment: No, I have a sample form with "patient_id" on it, and I algo show a few other patient attributes. But yes, ever I create or update a sample, it has to have patient attributes

Comment: Your answer to my question is confusing, so could you please add the form you're talking about to your question?

Comment: I have a form to insert/update samples. Inside that form I have a partial for the patient fields (name and date birth). Sorry for not posting the form but it's too big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about this in a couple of different ways. First, you could try an `after_save` method as follows:

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_patient

  def update_patient
    if self.class.where(patient: self.patient).maximum(:dateOfSample) == self.dateOfSample
      self.patient.update_attributes(infantBreastFeeding: infantBreastFeedingAtThisTime,
                                     typeBreastFeeding: typeBreastFeedingAtThisTime,
                                     idadeDesmame: idadeDesmameAtThisTime)
    end
  end
end
```

Second, you could set the attributes in your controller on a create or update.

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
  # call this in both your create and update methods before you save
  def assign_sample_attributes_to_product        
    if Sample.where(patient: @sample.patient).maximum(:dateOfSample) < @sample.dateOfSample)
      @sample.assign_attributes(infantBreastFeeding: @sample.infantBreastFeedingAtThisTime,
                                typeBreastFeeding: @sample.typeBreastFeedingAtThisTime,
                                idadeDesmame: @sample.idadeDesmameAtThisTime)
    end
  end
end
```

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: I tried option 1 and I get: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0), related to "max"

Comment: Whoops sorry! It should be `maximum`, not `max`. I always get those mixed up. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I was looking for an alternative to max but you beat me :) I loved your solution, the code is much cleaner and elegant than what I was trying to write!

Comment: These solutions make me love even more RoR :) the more I learn the more I like it!

Comment: I feel the exact same way. RoR is fantastic.